# Approve Disapprove or Neutraprove!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting

Why give users the ability only to approve or disapprove of an answer.
We know there is that sweet middle ground we a person could feel,
"Its an answer, but nothing to write home about."

Enters **Neutraprove**

It will give a better focus to an OK but potentially real answer.

***UPDATE***

To make a clarification:

Abstaining from a vote is not the same as saying "Good point, but not the best".

Hence **Neutraprove**

Comment: Why stop there? Let's give each answer a "star rating," like they do on IMDB.  (Sarcasm, in case you were wondering)

Answer (score 12):

Assuming approve/disapprove refer to upvote/downvote respectively, another word for this "neutraprove" is abstinence, i.e. abstinence from voting altogether.

In other words, if you don't find an answer remarkable, you don't have to vote on it.

Comment: I am reminded of the Bush administration.